# Configure Glassfish v3 with pac file?

Tags: proxy, glassfish, glassfish-3, webservice-client

I have web service client deployed on Glassfish v3.  It needs to access a server that requires proxy access.  I have a pac file (proxy auto config) but I don't if/how I can use this to configure my Glassfish instance so the my client can access the service.  If it's not doable, is there another way to set up access to a proxied server?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I did not need to configure Glassfish with the pac file. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any info on setting up proxy access with a PAC file, however you could set a hostname and port for a proxy server both for HTTP and HTTPS via JVM settings, see question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274041/how-do-i-set-up-glassfish-to-go-via-a-proxy-server/7274477).

You could set up a proxy on your localhost, which could handle a PAC file or mask proxy authentication. I use Authoxy for this for my local server on Mac OS X, no doubt there are similar programs for other OSes. Then set up your Glassfish to connect via the proxy on your localhost.