# How do I set up Glassfish to go via a proxy server?

Tags: java, proxy, connection, glassfish

I have been having issues with running a Glassfish v2.1.1 instance on my local machine from within the office, where we have a proxy server for outgoing connections. My initial workaround has been to work from home.

I am calling a SOAP service on a HTTPS server outside of the company. As Glassfish is not going via the company's proxy server, I get the following error when trying to initialise my SOAP clients:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://www.hostname.com...
```

and

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.hostname.com
```

I have proxy environment variables set on my command line, as well as my system proxy settings all working correctly so that I can get to the WSDL with the browser. How should I configure Glassfish?

Comment: `I am calling a SOAP service on a HTTPS ` - how ? via what web service API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a lot of trouble finding an answer to this, as the topic isn't covered in a lot of detail on the web. One link told me how to configure the HTTP proxy, but mentioned nothing about HTTPS, so it took me a while to figure it out.

Open up the admin console on your Glassfish server and go to:
Application Server -> JVM Settings -> JVM Options. Click "Add JVM Option" 4 times and enter the following 4 options

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostname
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyhostname
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

Where proxyhostname and the port number are correct for your setup. Then you need to restart the server.

Note that I couldn't find any options for setting up the proxy from a PAC file, nor for proxies which require auth. In this case, you may need to install a local auth proxy handler like Authoxy for Mac OS X, which turns your localhost into a non-auth proxy and masks the authentication request from the central auth proxy.

Also, this link was good for various proxy options to the JVM:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: What about user and password?

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly set the proxy server. Several options are available depending on the Glassfish version. In general you can set the proxy by either using JVM arguments or the Glassfish Admin console. An intro for GF3 is available [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/survivant/archive/2009/03/how_to_configur.html) (sorry for only providing a link, but I do not want to repeat all the details here).

Comment: This is correct, the site you link to has some good tips. However in GFv2.1 the options have to be entered as "-DhttpProxy=hostname" and not "httpProxy=hostname" as mentioned on the site. Also, it doesn't mention the HTTPS settings, which I have discovered exist also in the JVM settings. See link in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the answer complete, if the proxy requires user name and password, set the following in Glassfish:

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword
```

Answer (score 0):

The host cannot be resolved, are you sure you use a hostname resolvable by an internet DNS server or are you using something that can only be resolved from within your network or even worse, a hosts entry local to your machine?
Aside from that, the proxy server might be denying you access to some ports, but this is probably not your problem right now. If the proxy allows access to port 80, try running your Glassfish on port 80 as well if you get any connection timeout errors.